# ServerRequest on SpringBoot 2.0.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, reactive-programming

I recently moved my app. from Spring Boot 1 to Spring Boot 2 (2.0.0.RELEASE).

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I want to import the class `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest` to get the Error Attributes from the interface

```
org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.error.ErrorAttributes;
```

but I got this error:

```
The import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest cannot be resolved
```

Comment: could you your full pom.xml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spring Boot Reactive Project `spring-boot-web-reactive` was merged into [Spring Webflux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html) with Spring 5.0

Make sure you have `webflux` Starter on your classpath:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```